# How to use Bing Search Cognitive Service API to get instant answers

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-api, bing-search

We are working with Microsoft Bot framework and QnAmaker. When there is no question is found in Knowledge base, we like to search using Bing and get the answers. We are able to get the all results except the answer that shown in the below image with red box. Could anyone help me to get the content/description from the box shown in the red colored rectangle.

[image: Bing results for linkedin+Follower]

The link for the API request is [https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=linkedin%20followers](http://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=linkedin%20followers)
 and the same search using bing is [https://www.bing.com/search?q=linkedin+followers](https://www.bing.com/search?q=linkedin%20followers)

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new experimental API from microsoft. It is called **"Project Answer Search API**". It can help you retrieve **"instant answers"**. The API will output a JSON and you can find the **"instant answer"** under **"description"** key in json.

https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-answer-search

Hope this helps.